# why f1.Read(buf) doesn't read out content to buf?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io"
)

func main() {

    f1,_ := os.Create("f1")

    io.WriteString(f1, "some content")

    buf := make([]byte, 8)

    f1.Read(buf)

    fmt.Println(buf)

}
```

I create a file, then write in some string. then read out, but there is no content.

The output is :

```
go run test.go
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: The `Read` method returns an error, please check that error and if it's `nil` or it's message is not clear come back. Same for `WriteString`. But it's probably the cursor, it's at the end of the file after `WriteString` https://play.golang.org/p/nCfxvaAg0y6. You would see that if you checked the error from Read, you would get EOF.

Comment: error is EOF, didn't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go, don't ignore errors. When writing to and reading from a file, keep track of the current file offset.

After the write the offset is at the end-of-file, you need to set the offset to the start-of-file before the read. For example, with diagnostic information,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f1, err := os.Create("f1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer f1.Close()
    // The file offset is its current location.
    s, err := f1.Seek(0, io.SeekCurrent)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(s, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("offset:", s)
    // writing takes place at the file offset, and
    // the file offset is incremented by the number of bytes actually
    // written.
    n, err := f1.WriteString("some content")
    fmt.Println("write: ", n, err)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(n, err)
        return
    }
    // The file offset is its current location
    s, err = f1.Seek(0, io.SeekCurrent)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(s, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("offset:", s)

    buf := make([]byte, 8)

    // the read operation commences at the
    // file offset, and the file offset is incremented by the number of
    // bytes read.  If the file offset is at or past the end of file, no
    // bytes are read, and read() returns zero.
    n, err = f1.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])
    fmt.Println("read:  ", n, err)
    buf = buf[:n]
    fmt.Println("buffer:", len(buf), buf)
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(n, err)
            return
        }
    }

    // The file offset is set to the start-of-file.
    s, err = f1.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(s, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("offset:", s)
    // the read operation commences at the
    // file offset, and the file offset is incremented by the number of
    // bytes read.  If the file offset is at or past the end of file, no
    // bytes are read, and read() returns zero.
    n, err = f1.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])
    fmt.Println("read:  ", n, err)
    buf = buf[:n]
    fmt.Println("buffer:", len(buf), buf)
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(n, err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/hPUn1ltKP2t

Output:

```
offset: 0
write:  12 <nil>
offset: 12
read:   0 EOF
buffer: 0 []
offset: 0
read:   8 <nil>
buffer: 8 [115 111 109 101 32 99 111 110]
```

Comment: The Writer and Reader share offset, That's the reason. Before I think they doesn't affect each other.

Comment: @JinlongWang: The offset is a property of `os.File`, that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Generally because the written information might have not been flushed and stored to disk for reading. Try closing the file and reopening it for reading:

```
f1, _ := os.Create("/tmp/f1")

io.WriteString(f1, "some content")
f1.Close()

buf := make([]byte, 8)

f1, _ = os.Open("/tmp/f1")

f1.Read(buf)

fmt.Println(buf)
```

Prints

> [115 111 109 101 32 99 111 110]

Interestingly though, if you just get a different handler to that file, it will also work. However, I suspect this might be very unstable and dependent on the OS specific file system implementation (OSX APFS in my case). The write is only truly complete with `Close` returning no error:

```
f1, _ := os.Create("/tmp/f1")

io.WriteString(f1, "some content")

buf := make([]byte, 8)

f2, _ := os.Open("/tmp/f1")

f2.Read(buf)

fmt.Println(buf)
```

Prints:

> [115 111 109 101 32 99 111 110]

**Correction**: as the below comment suggests, rewinding the cursor on the same handle should work as well:

```
f1, _ := os.Create("/tmp/f1")

io.WriteString(f1, "some content")

f1.Seek(0, 0)

buf := make([]byte, 8)

f1.Read(buf)

fmt.Println(buf)
```

Prints:

> [115 111 109 101 32 99 111 110]

Comment: It should be enough to just rewind the cursor with `Seek`. https://play.golang.org/p/nCfxvaAg0y6

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, all is because the Seeker.

Answer (score -2):

After writing to the file use `Seek` to read from the origin of file which will read the contents from the start and insert to `buf`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    f1, err := os.Create("f1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    io.WriteString(f1, "some content")
    buf := make([]byte, 8)
    f1.Seek(0,0)
    n, err := f1.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(buf))
    fmt.Println(n)

}
```

Output:

> some content 
>   12

Comment: "Actually when your creating a pointer to the file *File using os.Create.It reads to EOF." Actually, "[os] Create creates the named file, truncating it if it already exists." https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create